# How to install Visual Studio 2010 documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 Pro.  There might have been a link to install the offline help at the end of the install, but I missed it.  Now I can't find a way to install the help.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its for the RC but I guess its still the same check:

http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2010/02/10/how-to-install-local-help-content-after-installing-visual-studio-2010-rc.aspx